# EFCore query with multiple where clause that together act as AND but not OR

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-3.0

This is very obvious but tricky question. I could not find its answer on web or simply i am missing keywords that could find its answer.

Let's say we have many conditions based on which we want to filter data. These conditions are in multiple blocks. How to write them so that they work as `AND` clause but not `OR` providing they participate only in certain condition.

```
    var query = _entities.AsQueryable();

    if (model.CityId != default)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.CityId == model.CityId);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.PostalCode))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Proppostcode == model.PostalCode);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.AirportCode))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.AirportCode == model.AirportCode);
    }
```

Let me know guys if this question need more details. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> am I missing keywords that could find its answer?

Yes, This missing keyword is `Dynamic Expression` or `Dynamic Query`. If you follow these keywords you'll find a lot of solutions to your problem.

As [this tutorial](https://entityframework.net/dynamic-query) said:

> `Dynamic Query` allows you to perform **dynamic** `where` clause, `select`, `order by`, with string expression **at runtime**.

you can follow below links, too:

- [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express)
- [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries)

good luck.